# Printing a newline

Tags: bash, sh

GAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH I don't know why I'm struggling so much with this.

All I want to do is make:

```
    file="$a"[command-here]"$b"
```

to make $file=

```
    a [newline]
    b
```

And yet no matter WHAT echo or printf I try to use, I cannot get it to work!! I just want a newline between a and b. Can someone bring me out of my misery?

file="$a""echo -e '\n'""$b" does not work, nor can any combination I can think of.

Comment: Whatever it takes to print a newline.

Comment: See my edit. I need to do it inside an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
a='foo'
b='bar'
file="$a"$'\n'"$b"
echo "$file"
foo
bar
```

Or use `print -v`:

```
unset file
printf -v file "$a\n$b"
echo "$file"
foo
bar
```

Comment: See my edit. I need to do it with a and b being variables. Sorry I keep changing the criteria ><

Comment: THANK YOU. That's all I needed. Crisis averted.

Answer (score 0):

`sh` and similar shells preserve newlines in quoted strings. You could do this:

```
file="$a
$b"
```

for example:

```
$ a=foo
$ b=bar
$ file="$a
> $b"
$ echo "$file"
foo
bar
```